# Programmatically give Bevel effect for a linear layout in Android

Tags: android, android-linearlayout

**What I have**: I have programmatically created a adapter item for gridview image

**What I want to do**: I want programmatically give a Belevel Shadow as below in image

[image]

**Code I am having**:

```
linearLayoutOne=new LinearLayout(context);
linearLayoutOne.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,TableRow.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
linearLayoutOne.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
```

- ***How can I programmatically generate that effect-I do not want to use XML-background since I am generating views programmatically***
- Is it possible, if so how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just because you are generating view programmatically you can still set a background using an XML drawable.  Use

```
linearLayout.setBackground(drawable);
```

Where `drawable` is an XML shape definition.